# How to query based on nested object's key and value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
"session": { 
  "number": 123,
  "words": {
    "1": {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Hello"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Hi"
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 135,
      "name": "Hey"
    }
  }
}
```

We have data in MongoDB database in the given structure which I am not able to modify.

I can get the object based on query `session.number` is `123`, but now the challenging is we know the nested `name` is either Hi, Hey or Hello but the incremental key inside object words are unpredictable, is it possible to query base on the "name" field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$objectToArray` and convert the words property to an array then query it however you want, you can use the following:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            words: { $objectToArray: "$session.words" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'words.v': 'hi'
        }
    }
]);
```

You can read the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) for more info.